# How to add row into table with only autofilled fields on db site?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

I need to add multi language table to laravel site with structure :

```
 items ( id, created_at)
 item_trans (item_id, lang_id, name, data )
```

How can I add row into `items` table, if it has only autofilled fields on db site?

Field `created_at` in migration created with option :

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
```

With laravel `^10.8`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://blog.quickadminpanel.com/how-to-add-multi-language-models-to-laravel-quickadminpanel-2020/ did you try this ?

Comment: I have existing tables structure and have to follow it

Answer (score 1):

If your table `items` is just:

```
Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
});
```

You just need to do:

```
$item = new Item();
$item->save();

$itemTrans = new ItemTranslation();
$itemTrans->item_id = $item->id;
$itemTrans->lang_id = 1; // or other ID..
$itemTrans->name = 'John';
$itemTrans->data = 'Doe';
$itemTrans->save();
```

Just remember to auto-increment the primary key(`id`).